# Javascript: Get object name as string

Tags: javascript

Say I have this code...

```
var personA = {
    name: "john"
}

var personB = {
    name: "john"
}

function doSomething(o) {
    alert("Var is: " + o.toString()); // I need to convert 'o' to the object name
}

doSomething(personA);
doSomething(personB);
```

I want the alert output to be...

```
Var is: personA
Var is: personB
```

But I can't figure out how to get the name as string of the object?

Comment: You really want `personA`/`personB` in the output?? The names of the **variables**? Something tells me this is an X/Y problem -- you've asked about Y because you think you need Y to solve problem X, but it's likely that there's a better way to solve problem X than the above.

Comment: dosomething(personA.name.toString());

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22548989/4028085 You can do it like this if you make your "variables" properties of an object...

Comment: Why? What are you trying to solve by getting the variable names? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MojoDK check out my answer I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for but it is an alternative to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible. There is no connection back to the variable.

When you `doSomething(personA);` you get the **value** of the variable `personA` and pass that **value** to the function.

```
function doSomething(o) {
```

The value is copied into `o`. There is no path back to `personA` from there.

Comment: Although in this particular case, if you had access to the variables, and only one variable referred to each object, you could figure it out... But this is clearly an X/Y situation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically no you can't

A hacky way of doing it would be do have

```
var personA = {
    name: "John",
    variable: "personA"
}
```

and then just use `o.variable`

Answer (score 0):

```
var people = {
    personA: {name: "john"},
    personB: {name: "billy"}
};

for(var variable in people)
{
    alert(variable);
}
```

Code comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22548989/4028085)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of

```
var global = {};
Object.observe(global, function(obj) {
 console.log(obj[0].name);
});
global.personA = { name: "John" };
```

with [EC7 observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe)