# How to convert function arguments into key/value pair?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to find a way to make the following possible with NodeJS.

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30
d = 40
......
......

function getObject(a, b, c, d, ....) => {

    // this function should return an object.
    // return {
          a : 10,
          b : 20,
          c : 30,
          d : 40,
          .......
          .......
        }
   }
```

Is there a way to do it in javascript (NodeJS)?

[Edit - Solved]

As suggested by @Offirmo in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404057/determine-original-name-of-variable-after-its-passed-to-a-function) and @MarkMeyer in the comments, the problem in the question can be solved with ES6 object notation.

```
let a = 10;
let b = 20;

function getOject(data){
    console.log(data)
}

getObject({a,b}) // { a: 10, b: 20 }
```

Comment: How will you call the function?

Comment: The function will be called with n number or arguments (variables).

`getObject(a, b, c, d, ......)`

Comment: So if you can have code that calls `obj = getObject(a, b, c, d, ......)` why don't you just use `obj = {a, c, b, d}` and make the object that way? Why do you need a function?

Comment: So basically I want something like,

nameOfVariable : valueOfVariable pair.

Comment: Right, that's what `obj = {a, c, b, d}` does.

Comment: Instead of creating the object manually for n-number of variables, I want to generate it dynamically by just using the variable.

Comment: Oh! never mind, I see what you are saying. Wow! never thought it's that easy.

Comment: Would you mind adding it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: In that case this question is a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404057/determine-original-name-of-variable-after-its-passed-to-a-function and @MarkMeyer's solution is a dupe of @
Offirmo's solution there

Comment: I think you're right @duhaime

Comment: @duhaime, Thanks for pointing that out, that question didn't pop up for my search queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Offirmo in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404057/determine-original-name-of-variable-after-its-passed-to-a-function) and @MarkMeyer in the comments, the problem in the question can be solved with ES6 object notation.

```
let a = 10;
let b = 20;

function getOject(data){
     console.log(data)
}

getObject({a,b}) // { a: 10, b: 20 }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1:

It should be as simple as this :

```js
function test(a,b,c,d){
  return {a,b,c,d}
}

let result= test(1,2,3,4)
console.log(result)
```

---

#### Solution 2:

Generic Method for getting the parameters object, in any function...
Should work ... but it uses `arguments.callee` which is deprecated since ECMAScript 5  ( however it still does work in most major browsers.)

```js
function getArgumentsObject(fn,arg){
  let STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
  let ARGUMENT_NAMES = /([^\s,]+)/g;  
  let fnStr = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
  let names = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(ARGUMENT_NAMES);
  if(names === null) na,es = [];
     
  let obj = {};
  for(let a=0; a<Array.from(arg).length; a++){
    obj[names[a]]=arg[a]
  }
  return obj;
}

function test(a,b,c,d){
  return getArgumentsObject(arguments.callee, arguments);
}

let result = test(1,2,3,4)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, once you pass the values to a function, the function can not access the variable names.  Keep in mind, a value may be passed directly without a variable name.

```
const getObject = (a, b, c, d) => ({a, b, c, d})
const foo = 1;
const obj = getObject(foo, 2, 3, 4};
console.log(obj); // {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 d: 4}
```

In es6+ you can create a new object like this Mark Meyer states:

```
const obj = {a, b, c, d};
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to make use of the `arguments` object. We convert `arguments` to an array, and then we build an Object, based on the output. To get keys in alphabetic order, we'd use `String.fromCharCode()`.

```
const foo = function() {
  const _args = [].slice.call(arguments).reduce((obj, key, index) => ({
    ...obj,
    [String.fromCharCode(97 + index)]: arguments[index]
  }), {})

  return _args // { a: 1, b: "hello", c: 2, d: 3, e: "world" }
}

foo(1, 'hello', 2, 3, 'world')
```