# Protractor - How to print Parameter itself using console.log

Tags: protractor

I am trying to print the Parameter itself on console. my sample codes are like this:

```
it('should print the parameter value', async function(){
    expect (PO.printParameterandDoSomethingElse(myElement1)).toBe(true); 
}
```

the Page object is :

```
this.printParameterandDoSomethingElse = async function(ele){
   console.log(ele)
   //do something
   //do something else
   //return output
}
```

I was hoping to get "MyElement1" printed , but, in this code the console is printing "[object Object]" instead of the parameter itself (MyElement1). I found a discussion in the [github thread](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4094) where another user had the same problem but I could not find her SO thread. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the parameter name? I am assuming `myElement1` is an element so `[object Object]` is the expected output

Comment: Exactly!! I want the output of console.log(ele) to be "myElement1". Can we do it using any method?

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404057/determine-original-name-of-variable-after-its-passed-to-a-function) may be of use to you but as mentioned in it there is rarely a good reason to do this. The main answer suggests wrapping your your variable in curly braces  therefore converting it to a key:value pair in a JSON object `PO.printParameterandDoSomethingElse({myElement1})`. You can then access the key if you need to original variable name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine original name of variable after its passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404057/determine-original-name-of-variable-after-its-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're are passing to the function